# Problem with "Could not connect to the Gradle daemon" and IP address when running a Flutter app

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to launch the Flutter app (Flutter's version 2.10.3) on a Mac M1.

I made the next updates to the file `android/app/build.gradle`:

Some of my Android settings:

- `compileSdkVersion` from 28 to 32
- `targetSdkVersion` from 28 to 32
- `android/build.gradle`: `ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'`
- `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip`

I runned the app on an emulator API 32 (Android 12L), but the Gradle throwed an exception.

The log:

```
...
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not connect to the Gradle daemon.
Daemon uid: fd2e13e6-2566-45f5-8766-4fedc7775cb0 with diagnostics:
Daemon pid: 11467
  log file: /Users/<username>/.gradle/daemon/6.9/daemon-11467.out.log
----- Last  20 lines from daemon log file - daemon-11467.out.log -----
2022-04-22T14:07:40.973+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:4a:4965:170f:6161%en0
2022-04-22T14:07:40.973+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote address /192.168.1.251
2022-04-22T14:07:40.973+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface lo0
2022-04-22T14:07:40.974+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? true
2022-04-22T14:07:40.974+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Ignoring remote address on loopback interface /fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0
2022-04-22T14:07:40.974+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback address /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0
2022-04-22T14:07:40.974+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback address /127.0.0.1
2022-04-22T14:07:40.976+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpIncomingConnector] Listening on [bf4f42c3-7339-4aa4-8277-33e3ae19a1aa port:55627, addresses:[localhost/127.0.0.1]].
2022-04-22T14:07:40.982+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] Daemon starting at: Fri Apr 22 14:07:40 CEST 2022, with address: [bf4f42c3-7339-4aa4-8277-33e3ae19a1aa port:55627, addresses:[localhost/127.0.0.1]]
2022-04-22T14:07:40.982+0200 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonRegistryUpdater] Advertising the daemon address to the clients: [bf4f42c3-7339-4aa4-8277-33e3ae19a1aa port:55627, addresses:[localhost/127.0.0.1]]
2022-04-22T14:07:40.982+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonRegistryUpdater] Advertised daemon context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=fd2e13e6-2566-45f5-8766-4fedc7775cb0,javaHome=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/<username>/.gradle/daemon,pid=11467,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,-Xmx1536M,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=NL,-Duser.language=ca,-Duser.variant]
2022-04-22T14:07:40.983+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry] Storing daemon address: [bf4f42c3-7339-4aa4-8277-33e3ae19a1aa port:55627, addresses:[localhost/127.0.0.1]], context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=fd2e13e6-2566-45f5-8766-4fedc7775cb0,javaHome=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/<username>/.gradle/daemon,pid=11467,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,-Xmx1536M,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=NL,-Duser.language=ca,-Duser.variant]
2022-04-22T14:07:40.987+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
2022-04-22T14:07:40.988+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2022-04-22T14:07:40.993+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2022-04-22T14:07:40.993+0200 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] Daemon server started.
2022-04-22T14:07:40.994+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonStartupCommunication] Completed writing the daemon greeting. Closing streams...
2022-04-22T14:07:40.996+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] stopOnExpiration() called on daemon
2022-04-22T14:07:40.996+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] awaitExpiration() called on daemon
2022-04-22T14:07:40.996+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] daemon is running. Sleeping until state changes.
----- End of the daemon log -----

...
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem disappears when I change the settings of the ProtonVPN to a less secure configuration. There's a feature that is [Kill Switch](https://protonvpn.com/support/what-is-kill-switch/) that *protects your IP address in case you unexpectedly lose the connection to a ProtonVPN server.* [...] *This means that even though you can’t use the Internet until ProtonVPN reconnects, your IP address and DNS queries are safe from being exposed.*